# Android - Using Handlers?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, android-activity, handler

Is there any problem with using multiple Handlers in the same Activity.

I noticed that in all samples provided in android official website they use a single handler and detect different actions depending on the value of "what", is this because of memory management, and high amount of memory used by the Handler? Or should I call it "bad code" and do it the clean way (Multiple handlers each responsible for a specific task)

```
Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      if (msg.what == 0){
         // do something
      }
      else if (msg.what == 1){
         // do something else
      }
    }
}
```

OR

```
Handler taskHandlerA = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         // do something
    }
}

Handler taskHandlerB = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I wonder if a single handler is simpler to understand especially if you are using message based concurrency and do not want to worry about concurrent attempts read write to a shared memory counter with multiple handlers; instead with a single handler  I suspect that all the messages must queue up and block in the handler.

Comment: I use the Handler as a replacement for Blocks. In C you can pass a block of code around and let it get called by external objects without doing delegation. And I figured I could achieve the same thing by using Handlers in Java.

Comment: Hi aryaxt... Seems reasonable and if you use a single handler the "block" variables in the Activity should be "handler safe" :)

Comment: Hmm. The more I think on this, all of the handlers probably run on the single GUI thread, so never mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there isn't such a limit (a Handler is just a message receiver), but if you want to do such a thing the more common approach is to have one Handler that you post Runnable objects to.

Comment: is there will be any problem if I create multiple handlers on ui thread ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is some good reading on [Loopers and Handlers](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/).

When a `Handler` is created, it is automatically registered with its' `Thread`'s `Looper`.  This makes me think that you do not need multiple `Handler`'s for a single thread.  An `Activity`, specifically, one that uses multiple `Thread`'s, could use multiple `Handler`'s though.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Please answer me here http://stackoverflow.com/q/35443200/3593066 Thanks.  I need help

Comment: is there will be any problem if I create multiple handlers on ui thread ?